# When I had created verify phone number, I also get this like

Tags: php, laravel, class, laravel-5, verify

I got the message : Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RouteServiceProvider' not found

> Class in Verify controller

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Nexmo;
use App\Providers;
use User;
```

Calss in Longin Controller

```
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Redirect;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Nexmo;
use App\Providers;
```

How do you solve class problems?

Comment: You need to import the `RouteServiceProvider` class. But why are you trying to use a service provider in a controller?

Comment: @Martin Bean well, Oh I will do it again. Because of I trying import more and then I also forgot remove it.

Comment: @Martin Bean where is import it?

Comment: You import it at the top of the file like you do other classes. But again: why are you trying to import a service provider into a controller?

Comment: @Martin Bean Sorry I just that confused  of import, I had fixed ready.